# Visual HG and Visual Studio 2010 performance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, visualhg

I have been using Mercurial/tortoise HG and Visual HG as my DSCS with visual studio 2010. Of late i been experiencing noticeable delay while saving files in my VS solution (there 4 projects and each of those have about ~70 files each)
i am suspecting the delay could possibly be because of the Visual HG taking longer to readjust its icon upon saving a file. Does anyone here know any tricks/ tips to improve the performance?
(uninstalling Visual HG and going cmd prompt isnt one of those tips btw :))

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/disabling VisualHG to test your hypothesis that it is VisualHG that is at fault here? That's where I would start. At least then you know. If it turns out to still take longer, then it isn't VisualHG.

Comment: Good point. and i had in fact tried that before asking here :)

Comment: I've not noticed any issues with VisualHG and VS2010. And I use them *a lot*. That said, I only use VisualHG for the file status icons on Solution Explorer. Everything else it offers is fairly useless.

Comment: Well, i do use Visual HG for commit/ revert/ syncronize all that, and never had a problem with those - though i guess thats probably beside the point.